# What is the best way to UV unwrap a brick texture on a circular shape with the bricks aligned?

Tags: uv

I want to UV unwrap a gothic flying buttress and some other gothic objects (like gothic arches for example) which are often made of bricks. But no matter how I try to UV unwrap them, the bricks don't align with each other because the object has a curved edge, the same goes for the underside of the gothic arches. Is there a way to keep the bricks aligned using only one texture?

[image: [UV of gothic buttress]]

Comment: You could come up with a true 3D brick texture.. **if**  you don't mind that arches are not built that way.. really you need a radial set of blocks around the arch..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any automatic way, you can first unwrap with the *Cube Projection* mode, it will work on some sides:

[image]

It won't work on some other sides, you can still move the UVs in order to correct:

[image]

But it will always fail between some sides, imagine that you have a fabric with a 2D pattern that you need to wrap around an object, there's no way the pattern could align everywhere. Maybe make sure that the bad edges are invisible?

You could still make something perfect in *Texture Paint* mode if you paint the texture onto the surface with the *Draw* brush in *Stencil* mode, with this solution you could precisely rework all the seams between faces.